# How to set start page in PagerAdapter and swipe to next/previous page?

Tags: android

I have two activity. first activity have a list and second activity shows contents which is related to the chosen item of the list. I have created
a subclass of PagerAdapter in order to change contents of second activity by swiping needless to back to first activity and select next item. (exactly same as turning page). but the problem is when I select an item, second activity starts from beginning! and when I set setCurrentItem() method in instantiateItem() method in order to provide corresponded item's content, it works, but I can't swipe the page and change the text!
Anyway, I want to open a book from its middle and flip normally! :)
How can I eliminate these problems? tnx!

```
class MyPagesAdapter extends PagerAdapter
{
    @Override
    public int getCount()
    {
        return DataStorage.SIZE;
    }

    //Create the given page (indicated by position)
    @SuppressLint("InflateParams")
    @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position)
    {
        View page = inflater.inflate(R.layout.view_pager, null);

        DB.setTextDescription(position + 1);


        ((TextView)page.findViewById(R.id.textView1)).setText(""+DataStorage.ID);
        ((TextView)page.findViewById(R.id.textView2)).setText(DataStorage.EnglishTitle);
        ((TextView)page.findViewById(R.id.textView3)).setText(""+DataStorage.EnglishContext);
        ((TextView)page.findViewById(R.id.textView4)).setText(""+DataStorage.PersianTitle);
        ((TextView)page.findViewById(R.id.textView4)).setTypeface(typeFace);
        ((TextView)page.findViewById(R.id.textView5)).setText(""+DataStorage.PersianContext);
        ((TextView)page.findViewById(R.id.textView5)).setTypeface(typeFace);


        //Add the page to the front of the queue
        ((ViewPager) container).addView(page, 0);
        return page;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isViewFromObject(View arg0, Object arg1)
    {

        //See if object from instantiateItem is related to the given view
        //required by API
        return arg0==(View)arg1;
    }

    @Override
    public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object)
    {
        ((ViewPager) container).removeView((View) object);
        object=null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Unless you post code nobody can help you.

Comment: Have you tried using the setCurrentItem method

Comment: I've written in question that I've used setCurrentItem method! but it doesn't work properly!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see all your code but it should work like this.

When you switch from one `Activity` to another pass selected item ID via `Intent`. Inside `onCreate()` of your second `Activity` get that ID and then use it on `ViewPager`. Probably you will have to convert an ID to item position so you can call `setCurrentItem()`.